# How to contiune get input from readline(STDIN) after exception in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm trying to learn Julia by writing the classic guessing number game:

```
function main()
    secret_number = rand(1:10)
    println("Guess my number! ")

    guess_number =

    try
        int(chomp(readline(STDIN)))
    catch ex
        println("Invalid number. Please enter a number:")
        # how to continue here?
        int(chomp(readline(STDIN)))
    end

    while(guess_number != secret_number)
        validate(guess_number, secret_number)
        guess_number = int(chomp(readline(STDIN)))
    end
        println("You win!")
    end

    function validate(g_num,s_num)
        if g_num < s_num 
            println("Too small!")
        elseif g_num > s_num
            println("Too big!") 
        else     
            println("Equal")
        end
    end
```

This program could only handle exception from input (that is, if the user input is not a number), only once. The second time user input a invalid number, the program stops. How to handle parsing an `int` in Julia?

Comment: You made a few typos which I fixed for you.

Comment: @BrianTompsett Thank you. I'll pay attention to my typing next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A second loop, within the validation loop, to verify that `guess_number` is actually a number would solve this problem, e.g.:

```
function main()
    secret_number = rand(1:10)
    println("Guess my number! ")
    guess_number = 0
    while(guess_number != secret_number)
        valid = false
        response = ""
        while (!valid)
            guess_number =
            try
                valid = true
                response = chomp(readline(STDIN))
                int(response)
            catch ex
                if (response == "q")
                    return
                end
                println("Invalid number. Please enter a number:")
                valid = false
            end
        end
        validate(guess_number, secret_number)
    end
    println("You win!")
end


function validate(g_num,s_num)
    if g_num < s_num 
        println("Too small!")
    elseif g_num > s_num
        println("Too big!") 
    else     
        println("Equal")
    end
end

main()
```

This approach also applies the [Don't repeat yourself (DRY)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) principle by only obtaining the input in one line rather than two in the original code.

(EDIT)

As requested in the comments, I've also included a way to quit the `main()` function by entering "q" when asked for a number.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explaination, especially the application of `DRY` principle. The `while (!valid)` really shines here! I guess you must highly value the best approach in both programming and life. May I ask what's your favoirte programming book?

Comment: Is there a way to quit the `guessing game` without quit `julia repl`? `Ctrl-d`, `Ctrl-c, Ctrl-c` doesn't work during guessing number.

Comment: Glad to help. I have edited the answer to suggest a way to quit the `main()` function without quitting the Julia REPL. Making recommendations for books is outside the scope of Stack Overflow (being opinion-based) but my personal view is that "The Pragmatic Programmer" by Hunt and Thomas is a good source of the DRY principle (which is a deeper concept than just not repeating lines of code). Kernighan and Pike's "The Practice of Programming" is also excellent.

Comment: As expected, `q` quit the program. I searched online, found that `ctrl-c` is supposed to quit the program executation, and it doesn't work, which people complain a lot. I guess in the later version, Julia would be able to handle interruption by `ctrl-c`. Thank you for the `q` option - it solved the problem. The books you mentioned are of good reputation, I've added it to my reading list. Thanks again.